# JAVA: How to get information from JSON file with multiple entries, that are not exactly the same, without having many if statements?

Tags: java, json

Let's say that we have a JSON file that is like this:

```
[
{
  "id": "_oG_iTxP1pIC",
  "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Flowers For Algernon",
    "description": "A description ",
    "pageCount": 321
  },
  "saleInfo": {
    "isEbook": true,
    "listPrice": {
      "amount": 7.99,
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    },
    "retailPrice": {
      "amount": 5.75,
      "currencyCode": "EUR"
    }
  }
},
{...}, 
{...}, 
...
]
```

But not all entries are like this, in some entries some info does not exist (ex: salesInfo JSON Object may not exist at all)

I figured out that I could do something like:

(The parsed information is been saved in an Array List of Book objects)

```
if (book.has("id")) id = book.getString("id");
if (book.has("volumeInfo")) volumeInfo = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
if (volumeInfo.has("title")) title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
if (volumeInfo.has("description")) description = volumeInfo.getString("description");
if (volumeInfo.has("pageCount")) pageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");

if (book.has("saleInfo")) saleInfo = book.getJSONObject("saleInfo");

if (saleInfo.has("isEbook")) isEbook = saleInfo.getBoolean("isEbook");

if (saleInfo.has("listPrice")) listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");
if (listPrice != null){
   if (listPrice.has("amount")) listPriceAmmount = listPrice.getFloat("amount");
   if (listPrice.has("currencyCode")) listPricecurrencyCode = listPrice.getString("currencyCode");
}

if (saleInfo.has("retailPrice")) retailPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("retailPrice");
if (retailPrice != null){
   if (retailPrice.has("amount")) retailPriceAmmount = retailPrice.getFloat("amount");
   if (retailPrice.has("currencyCode")) retailPricecurrencyCode = retailPrice.getString("currencyCode");
}

this.listOfBooks.setNewBook(new Book(id, title, description, pageCount, listPriceAmount, listPriceCurrencyCode, retailPriceAmount, retailPriceCurrencyCode));
```

I think that this is not the correct way to do it. How else could you retrieve information from a file that has a lot of entries like the one above.

Can you convert the whole JSON Array into a list of Maps?

Thank you in advance for your answers

**UPDATE**

I updated the above snippet of the code I am using to parse the JSON into an object

The Book object that I am parsing the information for every book in the JSON file, is:

```
public class Book {
    private String id, selfLink, title, publisher, publishedDate, description, language, listPriceCurrencyCode, retailPriceCurrencyCode;
    
    public JSONArray authors, industryIdentifiers, categories;
    private int pageCount;
    private double listPriceAmount, retailPriceAmount;

Book(
            String id,
            String selfLink,
            String title,
            JSONArray authors,
            String publisher,
            String publishedDate,
            JSONArray industryIdentifiers,
            String description,
            int pageCount,
            JSONArray categories,
            String language,
            double listPriceAmount,
            String listPriceCurrencyCode,
            double retailPriceAmount,
            String retailPriceCurrencyCode
    ) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setSelfLink(selfLink);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setAuthors(authors);
        this.setPublisher(publisher);
        this.setPublishedDate(publishedDate);
        this.setIndustryIdentifiers(industryIdentifiers);
        this.setDescription(description);
        this.setPageCount(pageCount);
        this.setCategories(categories);
        this.setLanguage(language);

        this.setListPriceAmount(listPriceAmount);
        this.setListPriceCurrencyCode(listPriceCurrencyCode);

        this.setRetailPriceAmount(retailPriceAmount);
        this.setRetailPriceCurrencyCode(retailPriceCurrencyCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jackson library can parse this to a `List<TreeMap<String, Object>>`, yes, but you still need if statements...

Comment: Show the code that you're using to parse the JSON into an object, as well as the class that you are parsing it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate this logic into a method like this:

```
public Object getSafeValue(JSONObject item, String key, ItemType tp)
{
    if ((item == null) || (!item.has(key))) {
        return null; //The object was null or is missing the key
    }
    switch (tp) {
        case ItemType.STRING: return item.getString(key);
        case ItemType.BOOLEAN: return item.getBoolean(key);
        case ItemType.INT: return item.getInt(key);
        case ItemType.FLOAT: return item.getFloat(key);
        case ItemType.JSONOBJECT: return item.getJSONObject;
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Here, we have exactly one `if`: it's checking whether `item` exists and has the `key` we are searching for. From here on, you can call `getSafeValue` like this:

```
id = getSafeValue(book, "id", ItemType.STRING);
```

or this:

```
listPriceAmmount = getSafeValue(listPrice, "amount", ItemType.FLOAT);
```

Of course, `ItemType` is an `enum` with the purpose of guaranteeing ease of use.